# Kile doesn't provide preview but only a quick build

Tags: ubuntu, kile

I installed Kile since I understood it produces in the bottom of the screen preview of the TeX document I'm writing. When I installed it on my Ubuntu 14.10, I got only an option for a quick build (in Okular) and the preview field under my document is empty means:

[image]

Do I need to enable something in the setting to allow immediate compilation every time I type character/ formula in my document?

Comment: `Settings` → `Show Document Viewer` should be checked for that. If not check it.

Comment: I don't have `show Document viewer` under settings.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UoAp2.png. If this isn't coming, then I am clueless.

Comment: It doesn't exist in my menu. Furthermore, when I put there a lyx from another software and asks for quick preview of the section it previews in the bottom only a blank box.

Comment: you are using Kile 2.1.3 (the version that comes with the official ubuntu repos) while @HarishKumar is using version 3beta1 (the version which is installed by default in windows). Version 2.1.3 does not have live preview, the "preview" you are seeing is a snippet preview that lets you select some code (usually boxes or drawings) and visualize the result. If you want a complete document live preview you should switch to version 3, see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144205/automatic-update-for-pdf-with-kile/144216#144216) for more info.

Comment: I compiled now version 3 beta from source and I still don't have this option...

Comment: Note that 2.1.3 is the current stable version. Even Arch's package is 2.1.3 so I would be very surprised if any GNU/Linux distro was doing otherwise in a stable/production branch.

Comment: fine. so do you have any recommendations for latex editor (maybe with built in support in RTL languages) with live preview for ubuntu?